# OpenCV2.4.6 and VS12 error on contour drawing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, contour

I am trying to extract and draw contours from an image. 
The code I am chosing is mostly taken from the opencv sample code, But When ever I run this code , I got an exception error with message 
"First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFDCA9E5D in test1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000028EB40.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

, I've been looking for a solution but rather I found similar issue . 
Is there any solution on following code, because it is most common code if anyone tries to draw contours.

OR I would be very happy with others who are facing same error , if someone put an optimal or common solution for contour extraction

`

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    Mat img1 = imread("ima1.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat canny_img1;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RNG rng(12345);

    /*Using canny filter for feature extraction in image 1*/
    Canny(img1,canny_img1,1,3,3,0);

    /* Find contours*/
    findContours( canny_img1 , contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    /* Draw contours */
   // Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_img1.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    /// Draw contours
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_img1.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: I tryed it out. And it worked for me. Maybe an issue with 64bit dlls?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit . If you know any solution regarding 64 bit then it would be really great for people like me.

Answer (score 0):

For sample codes to run, you need to have your VS project configured correctly.

You can do this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html?highlight=visual%20studio%20installation

Some of the main points:

You have to go to project properties and set some things:

1) use staticlibrary or dynamic : for that you need to select correctly the appropriate directory in "Additional library directory".

Depending upon the mode in which you are trying to run the project "Debug/Release" if you use staticlib you need to add .lib files with "d" in it before extension.

2) Depending upon the 32 bit or 64 bit project which you are making you need to add appropriate dll directory to System Path.

3) You need to add "Include additional directory to "c\opencv\build\include"

Hope it will help